# File in S3 bucket is not updated on each lambda run

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

We have lambda which runs at every 5 minutes. We have logic to overwrite a file in S3 bucket. File is updated on alternate run but we want file to be updated on each run.

We have configured lambda to trigger for every 5 minutes.

```
  try {
    const result = await s3.putObject(params).promise();

    console.log(`File uploaded successfully at https://` + bucket + `.s3.amazonaws.com/` + key);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error');
  }
```

Above is the code to put into object. CloudWatch Evenet is configured with schedule expression "cron(0/5 * ? * MON-SAT *)"

Please advice on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi Byresh. Please add the relevant parts of the code of the Lambda, otherwise it is hard for the community to find out what is going wrong. Your code is most of the time the best place to start.

Comment: Updated the question with code.

Comment: What error do you get? Secondly, when you put this cron in the Cloudwatch event, does it give you the right preview of future triggers?(event give you a preview of next 10 triggers timing)